# How much time for an orange weapon?

Tags: dead-island

In Dead Island, orange-rarity items spawn in loot drops (e.g., weapon chest) at a high, if not 100% chance (outside of vendors) after a certain amount of time. This information was largely propagated by DeathMule across [fora](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=333959). DeathMule claims that the interval between this guaranteed-orange-weapon-spawn-chance (owsc) is five hours. I feel that this claim draws an arbitrarily high time beyond and rather than the true value. Is it true that it takes exactly five hours or does it take a shorter length of time?

Comment: so what exactly was your question? im a little confused now.

Comment: @Marco He's asking if he can glitch a game to manipulate a bug within the game to his expectations. My answer? **"YES, but you may cause the end of the world by doing so."**

Comment: No, I'm not asking if I can glitch a game. I already know how to. The questions that I ask may be related to glitching, but I could phrase them in such a way to never mention glitching at all. The fact that orange weapons are guaranteed to spawn after a certain amount of time (and only then, outside of vendors) is a fundamental game mechanic which doesn't involve glitching.

Comment: I've removed the secondary question. I asked it because it was esoteric enough not to warrant its own question, but related enough that I figured that I could get it answered as well. Learning about the time-based orange-weapon-spawn-chance and ability to manipulate its repeated spawn in a short time spawn would allow the secondary question to be tested much more easily.

Comment: I've removed the following phrase to avoid my question's association with glitching: "I've confirmed this by manipulating the save/checkpoint system to spawn multiple orange items in a row." It is clear, Ender, that you see my question in a bad light as a result of your misinterpretation. I merely added the phrase to add veracity to the phenomenon that I introduce.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, there is no set period of time before the game provides you with an orange-rarity weapon. Across multiple playthroughs I can attest that while the weapon distribution seems random, it generally orients to your character level. At higher character levels your character is more likely to find higher quality weapons in searched containers.

Other than the post you've linked I have not seen any other indicator that weapons are distributed on a timed schedule. If it were true, few players would find more than five orange-tier weapons in a typical playthrough - far less than I've actually collected on playthroughs of my own.

When your character approaches experience levels where they can start regularly finding orange weapons I would claim to find a new one around every 45 to 75 minutes of playtime - a far shorter timeframe than DeathMule states. Regardless, it seems random as I have found two orange-rarity weapons within a ten minute period on more than one occasion.

If you are in search of powerful weapons try making use of [skull mods](https://deadisland.fandom.com/wiki/Skulls) to receive potent developer blueprints, instead.